# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("getProxy") is not a valid method for this service in

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, nusoap

I wrote a PHP code for calling a method from a WSDL webservice :

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/nusoap_client.php';
$merchant = '123123123';
$amount = '10000'; 
$ResNum = $_POST['ResNum'];
$RefNum = $_POST['RefNum'];
$State = $_POST['State'];
$TRACENO = $_POST['TRACENO'];
if ($State=='OK') {
$soapclient = new SoapClient("referencepayment.asmx?WSDL");
$soapProxy = $soapclient->getProxy();
$res = $soapclient->VerifyTransaction($RefNum, $MID);

if ($res <= 0)
echo 'verification failed';
else if ( $res == $amount ) {
echo 'it verified';
echo 'code rahgiri'.$TRACENO;
echo 'resid digital'.$RefNum;
echo 'number kharid'.$RefNum;
}
else {
echo 'error1';
}
}
else {
echo 'error2';
}
```

I get this error after call `getProxy()` method

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("getProxy") is not a valid method for this service in callback.php:27
    Stack trace:
    #0 callback.php(27): SoapClient->__call('getProxy', Array)
    #1 callback.php(27): SoapClient->getProxy()
    #2 {main}
      thrown in callback.php on line 27
```

Aslo we need to solve this problem.

How to ?

Thank you

Comment: you have to use full address in `$soapclient = new SoapClient("referencepayment.asmx?WSDL");` such as `http://domain.com/referencepayment.asmx?WSDL`